# Read entire elements from an XML network stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, networking

I am writing a network server in C# .NET 4.0. There is a network TCP/IP connection over which I can receive complete XML elements. They arrive regularly and I need to process them immediately. Each XML element is a complete XML document in itself, so it has an opening element, several sub-nodes and a closing element. There is no single root element for the entire stream. So when I open the connection, what I get is like this:

```
<status>
    <x>123</x>
    <y>456</y>
</status>
```

Then some time later it continues:

```
<status>
    <x>234</x>
    <y>567</y>
</status>
```

And so on. I need a way to read the complete XML string until a status element is complete. I don't want to do that with plain text reading methods because I don't know in what formatting the data arrives. I can in no way wait until the entire stream is finished, as is often described elsewhere. I have tried using the XmlReader class but its documentation is weird, the methods don't work out, the first element is lost and after sending the second element, an XmlException occurs because there are two root elements.

Comment: I doubt XmlReader is the way to go, as it would expect a root element and it's not geared up for continuously streaming XML elements.  Usually when handling socket based connections, you would be listening to the connection and looking to identify the start and end of each  chunk of data.  I know you said you don't want to, but I'd expect that you'd have to use plain text reading methods to at least identify a chunk of XML that you can then parse.

Comment: you need to instantiate a new reader each message, where message is a complete node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
{
    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();

        var doc = XDocument.Load(reader.ReadSubtree());

        Console.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}",
            (int)doc.Root.Element("x"),
            (int)doc.Root.Element("y"));

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: This already comes close to it. It can read multiple XML root elements in the same stream, but the ReadEndElement call will always block until the next element comes in. Can I safely remove it or will I have to wait for another event?

Comment: If it's ReadEndElement that blocks and not ReadSubtree, you can simply process the XDocument before the ReadEndElement call.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the "conformance level" to "fragment", it might work with the `XmlReader`.

This is a (slightly modified) example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx):

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(streamOfXmlFragments, settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`XElement.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load.aspx) which is meant more for streaming of Xml Element fragments that is new in .net 3.5 and also supports reading directly from a stream.

Have a look at [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx)

I think that you may well still have to add some control logic so as to partition the messages you are receiving, but you may as well give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's anything built-in that does that.
I'd open a string builder, fill it until I see a `</status>` tag, and then parse it using the ordinary XmlDocument.

Comment: P.S. I know you wrote you don't want to use String methods, but I'm pretty sure it's your only way.

Answer (score 0):

Not substantially different from dtb's solution, but linqier

```
static IEnumerable<XDocument> GetDocs(Stream xmlStream)
{
    var xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, xmlSettings))
    {
        var xmlPathNav = new XPathDocument(xmlReader).CreateNavigator();
        foreach (var selectee in xmlPathNav.Select("/*").OfType<XPathNavigator>())
            yield return XDocument.Load(selectee.ReadSubtree());
    }
}
```

I ran into a similar problem in PowerShell, but the asker's question was in C#, so I've attempted to translate it (and verified that it works).  [Here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/reading-xml-document-fragments-in-net/) is where I found the clue that got me over the last little bumps (". . .The way the XPathDocument does its magic is by creating a “transparent” root node, and holding the fragments from it. I say it’s transparent because your XPath queries can use the root node axis and still get properly resolved to the fragments. . .")

The fragments of XML I'm working with happen to be smallish.  If you had bigger chunks, you'd probably want to look into [XStreamingElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement(v=vs.110).aspx) - it can add a lot of complexity but also greatly decrease memory usage when dealing with large volumes of XML.