# How to transform from SQL Server raw XML to C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a CLR stored procedure that receives raw XML as a parameter, for example:

```
SET @xml = (SELECT * FROM titles FOR XML RAW)
```

Will give

```
<row id="1" description="Mr." />
<row id="2" description="Mrs." />
```

The above `@xml` is passed to a generic CLR stored procedure that in turn needs to parse the data it receives.

Is there a simple way to transform the raw XML into a list in C#?

Comment: Will it contain a root node of any description or just the individual row nodes?

Comment: @YannickMeeus It's just the raw xml as shown above. I'd rather not transform into full xml in order to keep the size small.

Comment: You'll need to either use an XmlReader with a conformance type of fragment or add a root node and use XmlDocument,  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186225/c-sharp-xdocument-load-with-multiple-roots.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comments below.

```
var xml =  XDocument.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", @"<row id=""1"" description=""Mr."" /><row id=""2"" description=""Mrs."" />"));

var rows = from node in xml.Descendants("row")
           select new
           {
               Id = node.Attribute("id").Value,
               description = node.Attribute("description").Value
           };
```

The above will first wrap your xml in a mandatory `root`, it doesn't need to be called root but XDocument requires there to be a root node, otherwise it'll throw a wobbly.

Then using linq-to-XML, we're parsing the attributes of every `row` node into a list of anonymous objects. You can also create a typed object and parse it that way, but this really depends on your requirements.

Comment: I need the transform from Xml to a list in C#.

Comment: Completely missed that -.-, give me a sec and I'll see if I can dig up an example.