# Convert multiple XML to C# Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

I have multiple XML files as string in C# and i want to convert this string to C# Array.
I am trying through xmldocument but it throughs following exception.
"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 463, position 1."

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(context.Request.Params[2]);
```

Please help me how can i convert multiple xml files (string) to c# array.

Comment: Error is self explanatory. Please show your xml

Comment: @GiladGreen due to sensitive data i can't show that.

Comment: Then we can't help. Your xml is not valid in line Line 463. your code is fine.

Comment: Then how can we help you? Show a small section on it and remove the sensitive data from it

Comment: The line number in error is where the second file is starting

Comment: you have multiple files in the same big string?

Comment: @GiladGreen yes

Comment: Wouldn't splitting the string with "end of file" and loading each xml separately better ?

Comment: Why hold multiple files in same variable. Have an array of them and in each a separate file. Without seeing better how the data is kept I cannot give a proper solution.. but problem is because they are together

Comment: @Rafalon i am sending multiple files in an array from front end that is becoming cumulative string in c#. should i split it and then call the loadxml method or any other solution ?

Comment: Yes, I think you should find what char or what string is added between each file and split the whole string by this char or string (or try to get it in an array at the beginning, maybe with json ?).

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate multiple XML file contents into a single string because the string now contains multiple XML [root elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), which is not allowed by the [XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-well-formed).  Instead, load each separately.  If you must somehow parse such a concatenated string, see [C# XDocument Load with multiple roots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18186225).

Comment: You xml file is not "Well Formed".  You can sitll read file using XmlReader() method by setting the following :  settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;.  I would like to see the xml file before posting any code.

Comment: Actually file is too large and have confidential data, that's why not possible to remove all the data and post here.