# carriage return <CR> creates strange behavior in XmlReader.ReadOuterXml

Tags: .net, powershell, xmlreader

I have been troubleshooting this script  https://gist.github.com/Wimpje/a796ba134d61552587a7#file-splitxml-ps1

It does not work on some of my files and in my opinion it should not work at all but it does - in some circumstances.
If you consider this sample it should not work since ReadOuterXml() will/should move the position the next tag. It does work however,
If we switch to sample1 we get the expected result i.e. every 2nd node is missed

```
$global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$content1 = '<test><list_items><item><id>A</id></item><item><id>B</id></item></list_items></test>' | out-file -Force -filepath D:\test\sample1.xml
$content2 = '<test>' + [char]13 + '<list_items>' + [char]13 +'<item> '+ [char]13 +'<id>A</id>' + [char]13 + '</item>' + [char]13 + '<item>' + [char]13 + '<id>B</id>' + [char]13 + '</item>' + [char]13 + '</list_items>' + [char]13 + '</test>' | out-file -Force -filepath D:\test\sample2.xml

$file = (resolve-path D:\test\sample2.xml).path
#$file = (resolve-path D:\test\sample1.xml).path

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($file) 

$matchesCount = $idx = 0

try {
  
    $result = $reader.ReadToFollowing("item")
    $hasNextSibling = $true
    while (-not($reader.EOF) -and $result -and $hasNextSibling) {  #JONVIK
          write-host $reader.ReadOuterXml()
          $hasNextSibling = $reader.ReadToNextSibling("item")
    }

}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

output with Sample2

```
<item> 
<id>A</id>
</item>
<item>
<id>B</id>
</item>
```

output with Sample1

```
<item><id>A</id></item>
```

Why and how should it be done?

For now I have made this fix. Not sure it covers all possibilities

```
if  ($reader.Name -eq "item") {
    $hasNextSibling = 1
} else {
    $hasNextSibling = $reader.ReadToNextSibling("item")
}
```

Comment: It is unclear of what the referred script is supposed to do and more important what *you* expecting it to do. E.g. what if the xml file can't be split without invalidating de xml structuur? Is there a *used case* for this? Show examples of what you **input**, the *actual* results *and* expected results. E.g. in `<parent><item><id>A</id></item><item><id>B</id></item></parent>`, imaging that `A` and `B` represent lots of embedded data, how should that file split considering that this is all containt in a single `<parent>` node???

Comment: I am also confused. Is it perhaps looking for multiple root elements and splitting based on that?

Comment: The wanted result is that both <item> nodes are printed. Excepted output is what we get if we input sample2.

The expected behavior  on the other hand is that .ReadOuterXml()  forwards the position as per the MS documentation - as it does with sample1. 

The use case is to split an XML as advertised in 
https://gist.github.com/Wimpje/a796ba134d61552587a7#file-splitxml-ps1

However, it does not always work.

I can fix it. The question is about the presented behavior

Comment: If you want all of it printed, why do you need to split it? And in what way do you want to split it? Please explain further. A much better version of that script might be a simple  Powershell conversion of this naswer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378442/14868997

Comment: The sample is made to illustrate the behavior that does not seem to match the documentation. I don't need to print it to split. I need to read the node i order to split it and I need the read to work in the same way for all xml

Comment: The unclarity remains: what is the purpose of the  `file-splitxml-ps1` script or what do you want to achieve? Why not the standard (.Net) `xml` methods? e.g.: `$Xml.Test.list_items.SelectNodes('*').foreach{ $_.OuterXml }` to select the embedded nodes?